# Async version of built-in print (stdout)

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a problem understanding some of the limitations using `print` inside an `async` function. Basically this is my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async amain(loop):
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop)

    try:
        # using session to fetch a large json file which is stored
        # in obj

        print(obj)  # for debugging purposes

    finally:
        await session.close()


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    res = 1

    try:
        res = loop.run_until_complete(amain(loop, args))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # silence traceback when pressing ctrl+c
        pass

    loop.close()

    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

If I execute this, then the json object is printed on `stdout` and the suddenly dies with this error

```
$ dwd-get-sensor-file ; echo $?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yanez/anaconda/py3/envs/mondas/bin/dwd-get-sensor-file", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mondassatellite', 'console_scripts', 'dwd-get-sensor-file')()
  File "/home/yanez/projects/mondassatellite/mondassatellite/mondassatellite/bin/dwd_get_sensor_file.py", line 75, in main
    res = loop.run_until_complete(amain(loop, args))
  File "/home/yanez/anaconda/py3/envs/mondas/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/yanez/projects/mondassatellite/mondassatellite/mondassatellite/bin/dwd_get_sensor_file.py", line 57, in amain
    print(obj)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking
1
```

The funny thing is that when I execute my code redirecting `stdout` to a file like this

```
$ dwd-get-sensor-file > output.txt ; echo $?
0
```

the exception doesn't happen and the whole output is correctly redirected to `output.txt`.

For testing purposes I converted the json object to a string and instead of doing `print(obj)` I do `sys.stdout.write(obj_as_str)` then I get this
exception:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

I've searched for this `BlockingIOError` exception but all threads I find have something to do with network sockets or CI builds. But I found one
interesting [github comment](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4704#issuecomment-348435959):

> The `make: write error` is almost certainly EAGAIN from stdout. Pretty much every command line tool expects stdout to be in blocking mode, and does not properly retry when in nonblocking mode.

So when I executed this

```
python -c 'import os,sys,fcntl; flags = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout, fcntl.F_GETFL); print(flags&os.O_NONBLOCK);'
```

I get 2048, which means blocking (or is this the other way round? I'm confused). After executing this

```
python -c 'import os,sys,fcntl; flags = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout, fcntl.F_GETFL); fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, flags&~os.O_NONBLOCK);'
```

I don't get the `BlockingIOError` exceptions anymore, but I don't like this solution though.

So, my question is: how should we deal when writing to `stdout` inside an `async` function? If I know that I'm dealing with `stdout`, should I
set `stdout` to non-blocking and revert it back when my program exits? Is there a specific strategy for this?

Answer (score 0):

Give [aiofiles](https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles/) a try, using stdout FD as the file object.

> aiofiles helps with this by introducing asynchronous versions of files that support delegating operations to a separate thread pool.

In terms of actually using `aiofiles` with an FD directly, you could probably extend the [`aiofiles.os` module](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles/blob/master/aiofiles/os.py), using `wrap(os.write)`.

Comment: I'm using `aiofiles` for other things, but I fail to see how to use `aiofiles` with `stdin` or `stdout`. At least the documentation doesn't explicitly say how to do that.

Comment: So you mean I could do this: `aiofiles.os.write = aiofiles.os.wrap(os.write)` and then use `await aiofiles.os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), b"Hello world\n")`?

Comment: Something like that, though might need `os.fdopen()`? (Not sure, int may work)  Sorry, busy today ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seen [aioconsole](https://aioconsole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

The aioconsole project provides a couple of straightforward [examples](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole/tree/main/example) for applying aioconsole directly in Python, and shell utilities for interactive applications.

For python programming under asyncio, aioconsole can be used within an async context manager (example below). Some thoughts, tho:

It's possible to use aioconsole for async stdio streams, generally *when the asyncio loop for the original async streams is running*.

For handling i/o in the duration between asyncio loop shutdown and when the Python process exits, hypothetically a context manager function could (sort of) dup the original i/o streams, then creating new Python streams (in a sense) to restore i/o onto the original filenos.

This approach may have some drawbacks, such as for data integrity in console i/o beginning at the duration of asycnio loop shutdown.

There is at least [one working test for this hypothetical approach](https://github.com/fxtatools/pyfx_dispatch_oanda/blob/main/src/pyfx/dispatch/oanda/util/console.py) though.

In the main part of this example, it defines a `console_io()` context manager, producing a ConsoleIO object for wrapping the aioconsole streams in something generally reminiscent of a UNIX PTY. It then sets the stdio streams to those produced by aioconsole. Before return, the context manager creates new streams for the original filenos of the sys out, err, and in streams.

This may not be compatible with ncurses applications at the console.

Limitations aside, the source code is included below, with the original annotations (author)

```py
"""Asynchronous Console I/O Support with aioconsole"""

import aioconsole
import atexit
import asyncio as aio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager, suppress
import os
import sys
import traceback
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias, Optional, Union


ConsoleStreamReader: TypeAlias = Union[aioconsole.stream.StandardStreamReader, aioconsole.stream.NonFileStreamReader]
ConsoleStreamWriter: TypeAlias = Union[aioconsole.stream.StandardStreamWriter, aioconsole.stream.NonFileStreamWriter]


class ConsoleIO:
    '''Streams wrapper for aioconsole via console_io()'''
    def __init__(self, loop: aio.AbstractEventLoop,
                 reader: aio.StreamReader,
                 out_writer: aio.StreamWriter,
                 err_writer: Optional[aio.StreamWriter]):
        self._loop = loop
        self._reader = reader
        self._out_writer = out_writer
        self._err_writer = err_writer if err_writer else out_writer

    __slots__ = ("_loop", "_reader", "_out_writer", "_err_writer")

    @property
    def stdin_reader(self) -> ConsoleStreamReader:
        return self._reader

    @property
    def stdout_writer(self) -> ConsoleStreamWriter:
        return self._out_writer

    @property
    def stderr_writer(self) -> ConsoleStreamWriter:
        return self._err_writer

    def close(self):
        ## close stdout, stderr writers without flush
        stdout = self.stdout_writer
        stdout.close()
        stderr = self.stderr_writer
        if stderr is not stdout:
            stderr.close()

    async def aclose(self):
        stdout = self.stdout_writer
        stdout.close()
        try:
            await stdout.wait_closed()
        except:  # nosec B110
            pass
        stderr = self.stderr_writer
        if stderr is not stdout:
            stderr.close()
            try:
                await stderr.wait_closed()
            except:  # nosec B110
                pass


@asynccontextmanager
async def console_io(*, stderr_out: bool = False, loop: Optional[aio.AbstractEventLoop] = None):
    '''Async context manager for aioconsole streams

    On entry to the context manager, creates a new ConsoleIO object for sys.stdin, sys.stdout,
    and sys.stderr. A new ConsoleIO object will be returned the caller, containing each of
    these asynchronous streams.

    The new streams are created with `aioconsole.stream.create_standard_streams()`

    Within the context scope of the context manager, each of the `sys` streams is replaced
    with the corresopnding aioconsole stream.

    On exit from the context manager, the stdout, stderr, and stdin streams are each set to
    the stream that was acvtive when the context manager was entered, then the ConsoleIO
    object is closed. By side effect, this will drain and close the asynchronous output
    streams.

    Known Limitations:

    - Provided as a utilty for general applications in console scripts, this context
      manager may not serve as a complete asyncio replacement for the operating system's
      PTY implementation, or for any PTY-like interface for the host system.

    - asyncio streams are each managed under the asyncio event loop for the primary thread.
      As such, this context manager may produce any undetermined side effects on event of
      error, and on event of unexpected loop closure.

      For instance, with Python on Microsoft Windows platforms, messages such as "Lost stdout"
      may appear during a bracktrace, in an application of this context manager.

      Output from Python Debug mode is not known to be adversely affected with this feature.
    '''
    pipe = None
    stdout = sys.stdout
    stdout_fd = os.dup(stdout.fileno())
    stderr = sys.stderr
    stderr_fd = None if stderr is stdout else os.dup(stderr.fileno())
    stdin = sys.stdin
    stdin_fd = os.dup(stdin.fileno())
    try:
        aio_loop = loop or aio.get_running_loop()
        s_in, s_out, s_err = await aioconsole.stream.create_standard_streams(sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr, loop=aio_loop)
        pipe = ConsoleIO(loop, s_in, s_out, s_err)
        sys.stderr = pipe.stderr_writer
        sys.stdout = pipe.stdout_writer
        sys.stdin = pipe.stdin_reader
        yield pipe
    finally:
        # Open a fallback stream for each original file descriptor
        #
        # This should serve to ensure normal I/O is available before sys.exit()
        #
        # Known Limitations:
        #
        # It's assumed that the original sys streams are each bound to some object
        # having a fileno(), furthermore assumed that the dup'd file descriptors
        # are each accepting I/O at this time
        #
        # Not a complete stream dup-lication, this does not restore buffering or other
        # properties of the original streams
        #
        sys.stdout = open(stdout_fd, encoding=stdout.encoding, mode=stdout.mode)
        atexit.register(sys.stdout.close)
        if stderr_fd:
            sys.stderr = open(stderr_fd, encoding=stderr.encoding, mode=stderr.mode)
            atexit.register(sys.stderr.close)
        else:
            sys.stderr = sys.stdout

        sys.stdin = open(stdin_fd, encoding=stdin.encoding, mode=stdin.mode)
        atexit.register(sys.stdin.close)
        if pipe:
            try:
                async with aio.timeout(sys.getswitchinterval()):
                    await pipe.aclose()
            except:
                print("Error during ConsoleIO.aclose()", file=stderr)
                traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), file=stderr)
            finally:
                pipe.close()
```